# Making something point-free in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, pointfree

I'm learning about the JS Library Ramda rightnow. And there seems to be a pattern i am unable to resolve properly. For example i have this code.

```
const filterPayments = filter => payments =>
  r.filter(
    r.allPass([
      typePred(filter),
      amountPred(filter),
      accountPred(filter),
      currencyPred(filter)
    ]),
    payments
  );
```

Now this seems to be a case where i'm not to far off beeing able to make it point free. I just can't seem to find the right way.

In addition i have troubles making logical functions like this completely functional and Point-free:

```
const amountPred = filter => p =>
  r.and(p.betrag >= filter.amount.min, p.betrag <= filter.amount.max);
```

Maybe somebody can point me into the right direction or offer some guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guidance I'd offer is to stick with what you currently have :)

I can show you an example of what point-free translations of what you have there could look like, though the resulting code is quite horrible to read and is really only good for a session of mental gymnastics.

First up, `payments` appears in the final position of both sides of the function expression so we can simply drop that.

```
const filterPayments = filter =>
  R.filter(
    R.allPass([
      typePred(filter),
      amountPred(filter),
      accountPred(filter),
      currencyPred(filter)
    ]));
```

Next we can look to deal with the list of functions passed to `R.allPass`

```
R.allPass(R.map(p => p(filter), [typePred, amountPred, accountPred, currencyPred]))
```

Now we can begin to remove the `filter` argument by flipping `R.map` to push it towards the end.

```
R.allPass(R.flip(R.map)([typePred, amountPred, accountPred, currencyPred])(p => p(filter))
```

Now lets make `filter` and argument to `p => p(filter)` instead of closing over it, making it:

```
R.allPass(R.flip(R.map)
  ([typePred, amountPred, accountPred, currencyPred])
  (R.applyTo(filter)))
```

This is now starting to take shape like `h(g(f(a)))` which we can transform to point-free using `R.pipe`, `R.compose`, `R.o`, etc.

```
const filterPayments = R.compose(
  R.filter,
  R.allPass,
  R.flip(R.map)([typePred, amountPred__, accountPred, currencyPred]),
  R.unary(R.applyTo) // R.unary is needed here to tell Ramda only to expect the first argument in this composition
)
```

This gives us a function that should now be equivalent to your `filterPayments` in point-free form.

Your `amountPred` example gets even more convoluted and I think you'll agree afterwards that what you already have is a much better choice between the two.

Again, we start by trying to push arguments to the end of each side of the expression:

```
filter => p =>
  both(
    x => x >= filter.amount.min,
    x => x <= filter.amount.max
  )(p.betrag)
```

And then we can drop the `p`:

```
filter => R.o(
  both(
    x => x >= filter.amount.min,
    x => x <= filter.amount.max
  ),
  prop('betrag'))
```

The functions passed to `both` can also be swapped out:

```
filter => R.o(
  both(
    R.flip(R.gte)(filter.amount.min),
    R.flip(R.lte)(filter.amount.max)
  ),
  prop('betrag'))
```

Now to tackle `filter`, we can use `R.converge` to pass the same argument to multiple functions and then combine the results of each together.

```
filter => R.o(
  R.converge(both, [
    f => R.flip(R.gte)(R.path(['amount', 'min'], f),
    f => R.flip(R.lte)(R.path(['amount', 'max'], f)
  ])(filter),
  prop('betrag'))
```

And now the `f` is in the end position, so it can be dropped by composition:

```
filter => R.o(
  R.converge(both, [
    R.o(R.flip(R.gte), R.path(['amount', 'min'])),
    R.o(R.flip(R.lte), R.path(['amount', 'max']))
  ])(filter),
  prop('betrag'))
```

Getting `filter` to the end is where it gets quite confusing, involving flipping composition functions.

```
filter => R.o(
  R.flip(R.o)(R.prop('betrag')),
  R.converge(both, [
    R.o(R.flip(R.gte), R.path(['amount', 'min'])),
    R.o(R.flip(R.lte), R.path(['amount', 'max']))
  ])
)(filter)
```

And finally...

```
const amountPred = R.o(
  R.flip(R.o)(R.prop('betrag')),
  R.converge(both, [
    R.o(R.flip(R.gte), R.path(['amount', 'min'])),
    R.o(R.flip(R.lte), R.path(['amount', 'max']))
  ])
)
```

... comparing that to your original, I know which I prefer to read:

```
const amountPred = filter => p =>
  p.betrag >= filter.amount.min && p.betrag <= filter.amount.max
```

Comment: Thank you! it's good to see, that you shouldn't always aim for the point-free and that it's perfectly fine to leave code without it.

Answer (score 1):

I had started to do the same sort of work that Scott Christopher did, and refactored the main function to point-free, knowing from the start that my advice would almost certain to be to not bother with point-free for this.  I found my point-free version, which was simpler than I expected.  Before I started on the predicates, I looked to see Scott's solution.

He did much what I would have done, and probably better than I would have.  And of course he ends with similar advice.  I always try to suggest that people don't make a fetish out of point-free.  Use it when it makes your code cleaner and more understandable.  Don't use it when it doesn't.

I wouldn't answer at all, except that I ended up with a slightly nicer point-free version of the main function, and would like to offer that up for consideration:

```
const filterPayments = pipe(
  juxt([typePred, amountPred, accountPred, currencyPred]),
  allPass,
  filter
)
```

Although this is fairly clean, I don't think it's as readable as your original, and so I wouldn't recommend it.  But if you really want point-free, this is a possibility.

Comment: `R.juxt` does clean this up a lot. Yet another function in Ramda that I forget exists :)